# Hibernate Iterator retrieving same data

Tags: java, hibernate, loops, iterator

I have a form that is connected to the database via hibernate. With this form, the user can go in and fill out fields such as names, address, and email information, etc. After they are all done filling out information they would submit the form. After submit, all the information would be display on a data table on the same page.

I am using session to interact with the database. However, the data that is being populated from database doesn't seem to be right.

```
public void somefunction() {

    //The sessionfactory is being configured in another class
    Session s = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
    Transaction tx= null;

    try {
        tx= s.beginTransaction();

        List userInformation = s.createQuery("FROM database1 WHERE PKEY ='"+somevalue+"'").list();

        for(Iterator iterator = userInformation.iterator; iterator.hasNext();){

            //database1 is an entity bean
            database1 x = (database1) iterator.next();

            System.out.print(x.getName());
        }
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(Exception) {......}
    finally {.....}
}
```

After the user submit the first "user" with their information, everything shows up in the datatable fine. However, when they enter a second "user" the row displayed on the datatable is the same information as the first user, even though the data is different. I think the code looks correct, so i am not sure what could be wrong with this.

Comment: check list size before  iteration?

Comment: The above code looks OK. Can you share your original code snippet? I am suspecting it's some object reference issue.

Comment: @user1817081 I don't see any primary key in your query. Change the name of the objects (mask) to maintain the confidentiality but post the exact snippet(don't share the full code). I am suspecting you may be using same object reference somewhere.

Comment: @user1817081 I think objectA  is an entity reference,why is it cast by objectA?

Comment: @Mohammod the code is updated.

Answer (score 0):

you should use primary key to get correct value.
 List userInformation = s.createQuery("FROM database1 where yourId='PK'").list();

In your query always it will return first row.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry forgot to add that part. I do have it filtering to a specific value in one of the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Instead of using `session.createQuery("QUERY")`, I used

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(SomeClass.class)

cr.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

cr.add(/* add some filters here */);

ScrollableResults sr = cr.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

while(sr.next) {
  someObject so = (someObject) sr.get(0);
  //Do action here
}
```

that solved my problem of returing a single result.

Comment: then it is caused by join.  I believe you can simply having `distinct` in HQL should work.  Even not, create a HashSet and put all result in the set should do the trick too (which is more or less how DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY is doing the trick)